# Accessing Nested data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am currently calling two json requests into my file:

```
d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {

   d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json2) {

   });
});
```

The structure of json 2 is like this:

```
[ 
  { "city" : "LA",
    "locations" : [ { "country" : "USA", "x" : 0, "y" : 0 } ] 
  }, 
  { "city" : "london",
    "locations" : [ { "country" : "UK", "x" : 0, "y" : 0 } ]
  }
  ... 
]
```

At the moment I'm trying to access to x & y values of json2. However, the problem I am having is that I wish to use both json & json2 in my variable:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("a.node")
 .data(json.cars)
 .enter().append("a")
 .attr("class", "node")
 ;
```

Here I wish to call json2 for the x & y positions ONLY

```
node.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});

node.append('path') 
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) { return shape [d.name]; }).size(120))
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colors [d.name]; } );
```

Is what I'm asking for possible.. I have tried the following:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    return "translate(" + json2.locations[d].x + "," + json2.locations[d].y + ")";
});
```

But no luck. any help would be great - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to select one of the objects in the array that contains the locations first. The locations is also an array of objects so you'll need an index to access that. Try this for getting the LA, USA x variable.

```
json2[0].locations[0].x
```

Comment: is that setting the x to 0 or will that actually read for the value of x

Comment: Hi @Dave Anderson I attempted to do so, however it had this affect: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/12/

Comment: Hi @Jose, that would read the x value for the first location in your first object in your json2 variable. You basically have an array of objects and within those an array of locations. You need to use an array index to get the object for a city and then another array index to get the location. Do you need multiple locations for a city? If you can change the json you get then drop the [] around the  location so it's o longer an array then json[0].location.x would work.

Comment: @Jose As you only ever have one location it seems to be the json2 index that needs to be iterated over. It's hard to tell from the fiddle if it works but something like `nod[i].locations[0].x` where i begins at 0 and is incremented for each item.

Comment: Ah I see! Would you know why this has disabled my drag function? http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/14/

Comment: @Jose not sure but you do know your `draw()` call is commented out?

Comment: Yes only because I had it twice so it would draw my node twice